# Will FCN-32s loss the spatial information (heatmap) if we design fc7 layer as 1x1x4096

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand of designing the network architecture in ["fully convolutional networks for semantic segmentation"](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf), J Long; and "[learning deconvolution network for semantic segmentation](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Noh_Learning_Deconvolution_Network_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf)" H Noh. In the FCN-32s the last layers are

> pool5(22x22x512)--conv(7x7x512)-->fc6(16x16x4096)--conv(1x1x4096)-->fc7(16x16x4096)--conv(1x1x4096)-->fc8(16x16x21)--upsampling-->output(544x544x21)

While, the DeconvNet is

> pool5(7x7x512)--conv(7x7x512)-->fc6(1x1x4096)--conv(1x1x4096)-->fc7(1x1x4096)--deconv-->output(224x224x21)

The main different between two papers is the deconvolution phase. I would like to ask something about the fc7 layer. The output of FCN is  16x16x4096 while the DeconvNet is 1x1x4096. Why the FCN-32s did not design to 1x1x4096 size and then upsampling to 544x544? Will FCN-32s loss the spatial information (heatmap) if we design fc7 layer as 1x1x4096? Thank you in advance

Comment: This hinges on two papers referenced only by their titles and authors. Minimally, you need to give full references and/or precise URLs that can be trusted to exist indefinitely. Beyond that, questions that depend on reading and understanding external sources are always problematic. Ideally, questions here should be self-contained; supporting references are fine.